# Kubuntu trackpad multifinger gesture support

Tags: kubuntu, kde, multi-touch, trackpad

I was wondering if there's a way to enable multi finger gesture support in Kubuntu 12.10.  I specifically would like to quickly be able to change desktop or minimise apps.  Other functionality would be great too - I guess I like the OSX way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, there is not multi finger gesture support in Kubuntu 12.10. At least in the way you describe.

But just in case some people comes here looking for help configuring their desktop environment, there are several options to change from desktops or minimize apps using the keyboard.

In the system preferences app "K-> Applications -> system preferences":
Go to Shortcuts and Gestures.
On the left go to Global Keyboard Shortcuts.
On the Top menu called "KDE component" select KWin. 
you could now edit all shortcuts of the desktop environment.

NICE TIP: you can save and load configuration files with all your favorites shortcuts for each component of KDE.

In newer KDE versions there is a new tool called Mouse Gestures that provides some functionality similar to the one described in your question.

There are more information related in:
[System Settings/Shortcuts and Gestures](https://userbase.kde.org/System_Settings/Shortcuts_and_Gestures#Global_Keyboard_Shortcuts)

Answer (score 1):

*en_US*: Try to use the `libinput`

### Details

You have to install the packages with APT:

```
sudo apt install xdotool wmctrl libinput-tools
```

And put your user to `input` group:

```
sudo gpasswd -a $USER input
```

Reboot... And install `libinput-gestures` with GIT:

```
git clone http://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures
cd libinput-gestures
sudo ./libinput-gestures-setup instal
```

Create the file `~/.config/libinput-gestures.conf` and inflate with your configurations. Example:

```
# Toggle Present Windows (Current desktop)
gesture swipe left 3 xdotool key alt+Tab
gesture swipe right 3 xdotool key shift+alt+Tab

# Terminal (I create the shortkeys in Kubuntu and apply it here)
gesture swipe down 3 xdotool key super+z
gesture swipe up 3 xdotool key super+z

# Show Desktop Grid
gesture swipe down 4 xdotool key control+F10

# Show Desktop                                                                                                                                        
gesture swipe up 4 xdotool key super+d                                                                                                                

# Show next desktop                                                                                                                                   
gesture swipe right 4 xdotool key control+alt+Left                                                                                                    

# Show previous desktop                                                                                                                               
gesture swipe left 4 xdotool key control+alt+Right

# Zoom (I create the shortkeys in Kubuntu and apply it here)
gesture pinch out xdotool key super+o
gesture pinch in xdotool key super+i
```

To set to autostart call this in terminal:

```
libinput-gestures-setup autostart
```

Reboot and enjoy :)

---

*pt_BR*: Tenta usar a `libinput`

### Detalhes

Instale os pacotes abaixo com o APT:

```
sudo apt install xdotool wmctrl libinput-tools
```

Agora, coloque seu usuário no grupo `input`:

```
sudo gpasswd -a $USER input
```

Reinicie... E instale o `libinput-gestures` com o GIT:

```
git clone http://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures
cd libinput-gestures
sudo ./libinput-gestures-setup instal
```

Crie o arquivo `~/.config/libinput-gestures.conf` escreva nele suas configurações. Exemplo:

```
# Trocar as janelas (Área de trabalho atual)
gesture swipe left 3 xdotool key alt+Tab
gesture swipe right 3 xdotool key shift+alt+Tab

# Terminal (Eu criei os atalhos no Kubuntu e usei aqui)
gesture swipe down 3 xdotool key super+z
gesture swipe up 3 xdotool key super+z

# Mostrar a grid de janelas
gesture swipe down 4 xdotool key control+F10

# Mostrar a área de trabalho                                                                                                                                   
gesture swipe up 4 xdotool key super+d                                                                                                                

# Trocar a área de trabalho com a esquerda                                                                                                                                   
gesture swipe right 4 xdotool key control+alt+Left                                                                                                    

# Trocar a área de trabalho com a direita                                                                                                                          
gesture swipe left 4 xdotool key control+alt+Right

# Zoom (Eu criei os atalhos no Kubuntu e usei aqui)
gesture pinch out xdotool key super+o
gesture pinch in xdotool key super+i
```

Para configurar para iniciar automaticamente, execute no terminal:

```
libinput-gestures-setup autostart
```

Reinicie e aproveite :)

Comment: en_US: Yes, I'll edit...
pt_BR: Sim, vou editar...

:D